# Can OpenSea royalty payments be made to a smart contract?

Tags: opensea

The goal is to test whether OpenSea will make royalty payments to a smart contract instead of a regular wallet. I'm curious as to whether they will incur possibly higher gas charges when the recipient is a smart contract. I cannot find any documentation on this, and I'm happy to test it on https://testnets.opensea.io/, but I cannot find information on whether they actually pay out test royalties on the testnets platform.

Since I can't test it, back to the question: does anyone know if OpenSea will make royalty payment to a smart contract?

Comment: @hedleyross, were you able to test/try this? I am curious as well.

Comment: I have not been able to test it yet, but according to @fredric it is possible.

Comment: Anyone tested the solution provided by @fredric, if so please mark it as the correct address

Answer (score 4):

Yes, royalties can be paid out to a smart contract (for example to a Payment Splitter). It says so on your collection's settings page, directly under the input where you provide the wallet address.

And no, they do currently not pay out any royalties on Testnet, so you need to test it live. Tip would be to maybe try testing it on Polygon, since the gas fees are minimal in comparison to Ethereum Mainnet right now.

Edit: https://docs.opensea.io/docs/frequently-asked-questions here's info about them not paying royalties on testnet.

> **When do I receive fees from secondary sales? Will I receive fees when testing on Rinkeby?** We send secondary fees to developers and
> creators once every two weeks, in one bulk transaction. In the future,
> this process will be automated, so you'll receive fees straight away.
>
> We don't currently send secondary fees on the Rinkeby test network.